# Are 2003-2004 Camry Power Seats Interchangeable?

Tags: camry, power, seat

My 2003 Camry Drivers Power Seat stuck in the furthest back position and will not move forward. I've read many of the same problems on here and removed the seat to find the problem. The 'left' side of the chair is working fine. The 'right' side (closest to the console) will not move forward. I was able to manually adjust the threaded shaft to allow me to put the seat back in so my daughter can drive it. She's short so it's almost all the way forward. It will move back, but not forward again.

I went to the junkyard and found the identical (or so I thought) seat in a 2004 Camry. It has an extra lumbar feature that my 2003 does not. However it also has (2) different wiring harnesses where my 03 only has one. The wires running back through the console have (6) wires. Whereas my 03 only has 5 cables coming from the engine. My 03 has a Yellow, Yellow/Black, Yellow/Green, Orange, and Red/Black wire. The wiring harness for the 04 seat has those plus an additional White wire.

Finally my question: **Can I still use the 04 seat and wiring harness and tie it into my 03 wiring?** I don't need the lumbar feature to work. If so, how do I splice the 6/5 wires together?

Comment: Doesthe white wire go to the lumbar feature? Trace all the wires to their functions then match the connector positions between the seats...

Comment: I tried splicing into the existing wires with the new wiring harness (all but the white one) but nothing would work. Is it possible all the motors on the 04 seat have died? How would I check?

Comment: Did you check what wires go zo each motor? I did say check each for function. I would check by using a battery and fuse to feed each motor pair of wires - usually the supply is reversed to change direction like window motors.